# How to add a libpcre3-dev and libpcre3 to docker image python:3.9-alpine3.13 when there is no such package?

Tags: python-3.x, dockerfile, uwsgi, pcre, alpine-linux

I need PCRE support for my uwsgi to running. So I planning to add `libpcre3` and `libpcre3-dev` to my docker.

This is my Dockerfile settings:

```
FROM python:3.9-alpine3.13

ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

COPY ./requirements.txt /tmp/requirements.txt
COPY ./requirements.dev.txt /tmp/requirements.dev.txt
COPY ./scripts /scripts
COPY ./app /app
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 8000

ARG DEV=false
RUN python -m venv /py && \
    /py/bin/pip install --upgrade pip && \
    apk add --update --no-cache postgresql-client jpeg-dev libpcre3-dev libpcre3 && \
    apk add --update --no-cache --virtual .tmp-build-deps \
        build-base postgresql-dev musl-dev zlib zlib-dev linux-headers && \
    /py/bin/pip install -r /tmp/requirements.txt && \
    if [ $DEV = "true" ]; then /py/bin/pip install -r /tmp/requirements.dev.txt ; \
    fi && \
    rm -rf /tmp && \
    apk del .tmp-build-deps && \
    adduser \
        --disabled-password \
        --no-create-home \
        django-user && \
    mkdir -p /vol/web/media && \
    mkdir -p /vol/web/static && \
    chown -R django-user:django-user /vol && \
    chmod -R 755 /vol && \
    chmod -R +x /scripts

ENV PATH="/scripts:/py/bin:$PATH"
```

And this is the error that I get:

```
 > [recipe-app-api-app 7/7] RUN python -m venv /py &&     /py/bin/pip install --upgrade pip &&     apk add --update --no-cache postgresql-client jpeg-dev libpcre3-dev libpcre3 &&     apk add --update --no-cache --virtual .tmp-build-deps         build-base postgresql-dev musl-dev zlib zlib-dev linux-headers &&     /py/bin/pip install -r /tmp/requirements.txt &&     if [ false = "true" ]; then /py/bin/pip install -r /tmp/requirements.dev.txt ;     fi &&     rm -rf /tmp &&     apk del .tmp-build-deps &&     adduser         --disabled-password         --no-create-home         django-user &&     mkdir -p /vol/web/media &&     mkdir -p /vol/web/static &&     chown -R django-user:django-user /vol &&     chmod -R 755 /vol &&     chmod -R +x /scripts:
#0 4.542 Requirement already satisfied: pip in /py/lib/python3.9/site-packages (21.2.4)
#0 4.820 Collecting pip
#0 4.970   Downloading pip-22.3.1-py3-none-any.whl (2.1 MB)
#0 5.584 Installing collected packages: pip
#0 5.584   Attempting uninstall: pip
#0 5.584     Found existing installation: pip 21.2.4
#0 5.680     Uninstalling pip-21.2.4:
#0 5.688       Successfully uninstalled pip-21.2.4
#0 7.017 Successfully installed pip-22.3.1
#0 7.268 fetch https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.13/main/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
#0 7.753 fetch https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.13/community/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
#0 8.331 ERROR: unable to select packages:
#0 8.356   libpcre3 (no such package):
#0 8.356     required by: world[libpcre3]
#0 8.356   libpcre3-dev (no such package):
#0 8.356     required by: world[libpcre3-dev]
------
failed to solve: executor failed running [/bin/sh -c python -m venv /py &&     /py/bin/pip install --upgrade pip &&     apk add --update --no-cache postgresql-client jpeg-dev libpcre3-dev libpcre3 &&     apk add --update --no-cache --virtual .tmp-build-deps         build-base postgresql-dev musl-dev zlib zlib-dev linux-headers &&     /py/bin/pip install -r /tmp/requirements.txt &&     if [ $DEV = "true" ]; then /py/bin/pip install -r /tmp/requirements.dev.txt ;     fi &&     rm -rf /tmp &&     apk del .tmp-build-deps &&     adduser         --disabled-password         --no-create-home         django-user &&     mkdir -p /vol/web/media &&     mkdir -p /vol/web/static &&     chown -R django-user:django-user /vol &&     chmod -R 755 /vol &&     chmod -R +x /scripts]: exit code: 2
```

So there is anything that can I do to add the following package?

I already trying installing with different name and searching a lot online, and still doesn't have an idea to add those package.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cannot install uwsgi on Alpine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36217250/cannot-install-uwsgi-on-alpine)

Answer (score 1):

Finally I can get my uwsgi run with installing `pcre-dev` package which mention by [β.εηοιτ.βε](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2123530/%CE%B2-%CE%B5%CE%B7%CE%BF%CE%B9%CF%84-%CE%B2%CE%B5) on [Cannot install uwsgi on Alpine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36217250/cannot-install-uwsgi-on-alpine)

So, this is my final Dockerfile settings:

```
FROM python:3.9-alpine3.13

ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

COPY ./requirements.txt /tmp/requirements.txt
COPY ./requirements.dev.txt /tmp/requirements.dev.txt
COPY ./scripts /scripts
COPY ./app /app
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 8000

ARG DEV=false
RUN python -m venv /py && \
    /py/bin/pip install --upgrade pip && \
    apk add --update --no-cache postgresql-client jpeg-dev pcre-dev && \
    apk add --update --no-cache --virtual .tmp-build-deps \
        build-base postgresql-dev musl-dev zlib zlib-dev linux-headers && \
    /py/bin/pip install -r /tmp/requirements.txt && \
    if [ $DEV = "true" ]; then /py/bin/pip install -r /tmp/requirements.dev.txt ; \
    fi && \
    rm -rf /tmp && \
    apk del .tmp-build-deps && \
    adduser \
        --disabled-password \
        --no-create-home \
        django-user && \
    mkdir -p /vol/web/media && \
    mkdir -p /vol/web/static && \
    chown -R django-user:django-user /vol && \
    chown -R django-user:django-user ./* && \
    chmod -R 755 /vol && \
    chmod -R +x /scripts

ENV PATH="/scripts:/py/bin:$PATH"

USER django-user
```